# Can I use different names for apps that are registered in the Android Play Store and the Android TV Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have now built the app in one package for Android and Android TV. I need to have a different name when registering the store. If the Android phone app registered in the store is 'a', then the Android tv app should be registered to 'a for tv' like this. What if there is any way. I can not find it on the console.

ps. The application name is the same! The names to be registered in the store must be different.

Thank you. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible. If you want to do that, register each apps.